# Can not add SVG to Fabricjs with image tag inside

Tags: svg, fabricjs

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 643 525">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path fill="none" d="M109,120c0,0,163,46,220,9s34-97,34-97s39.138-16.341,70-11c26.406,4.57,66.618,73.939,105,138
c37.199,62.089,73,119,73,119s10.398,18.504,0,44c-8.608,21.105-22.685,41.421-88.85,85.03C468.32,442.51,411,474,411,474
s-85,45-192,9l-5,1c0,0-34.254,15.226-60.675,10.088c-36-7-48.249-32.676-48.249-32.676S172,402,160,327S60,220,60,220
s-8.444-34,0-52C77.666,130.345,109,120,109,120z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image x="0" y="0" width="643" height="643" clip-path="url(#shape)" href="https://afamilycdn.com/zoom/640_400/2019/2/25/avatar1551079860411-1551079860411686096470-crop-15510798867791793347140.jpg">
  </image>

</svg>
```

I have svg file like this with image tag inside svg, but when I try to add svg to canvas fabricjs. It doesn't work anyway.

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function (objects, options) {
  var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
  loadedObjects.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });
  canvas.add(loadedObjects);
  canvas.renderAll();
},
  function (item, object) {
    object.set('id', item.getAttribute('id'));
    group.push(object);
  });
```

How can I handle svg like this?